# Function to match orders to batch not working

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, orders, nested-for-loop

```
#df =

  order_number  Product1   ...            Product 16            Product17
0   4329374937          1  ...                     0                    0
1   3483872349          1  ...                     0                    0
2   2394287383          1  ...                     0                    0
3   3423984902          1  ...                     1                    0
4   9378374873          0  ...                     0                    0


Batch1 = ["Product1", "Product2", "Product 6"]

for indices in df.index:
    for column in columns:
        if df[column] > 0 and in Batch1 df[B1] = True
      else df[B1] = False
    
print(df.head))
```

I am trying to determine a way to look through each order number and see if the orders which are greater than 0 are within my listed batch. I want to create a new column for each row that is a boolean. I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `df` is set to? I don't follow the explanation above.

Comment: It's pretty hard to read your example - are you familiar with how to format your question with code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to take the columns in your batch, add up the order numbers and see where it is > 0. So

```
batch_1 = ["Product1", "Product2", "Product6"]
df['B1'] = df[batch_1].sum(axis=1)>0
df
```

output:

```
      order_number    Product1    Product2    Product6    Product16    Product17  B1
--  --------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  -----------  -----
 0      4329374937           1           1           3            0            0  True
 1      3483872349           1           0           1            0            0  True
 2      2394287383           1           0           2            0            0  True
 3      3423984902           1           0           1            1            0  True
 4      9378374873           0           0           0            0            0  False
```